# Refreshing fetched properties of NSManagedObject

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass which has a one-to-many relationship and a fetched property that is set up in the data model to provide a filtered subset of the objects in that relationship.

```
//School.h
@interface School : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *pupils;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *starPupuils;
@end

//School.m
@implementation School
@dynamic pupils;
@dynamic starPupils;
@end
```

I then have a view controller that watches a School object for changes to pupils then refreshes the starPupils data:

```
-(void)setSchool:(School *)school
{
    …
    self.contentArray = [self.school starPupils];
    [self.school addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"pupils"
                     options:nil
                     context:nil];
    …
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"pupils"])
    {
        self.contentArray = [self.school starPupils];
    }
}
```

This works fine when the fetched property is first accessed but as expected the starPupils array is cached and does not update itself as pupils are added and removed.

> If objects in the destination entity are changed, you must reevaluate the fetched property to ensure it is up-to-date. You use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` to manually refresh the properties—this causes the fetch request associated with this property to be executed again when the object fault is next fired. — [Core Data Programming Guide: Relationships and Fetched Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

**My question is, where should I be calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` from?**

I've looked into calling it from the parts of the codebase that handle the adding and removing of pupils and that works fine when on the same context but often the changes take place in a separate background context.

This background context has its `parentContext` set to the `mainContext` that my view controller is always dealing with so when it is saved, the changes are automatically merged back in to `mainContext`. I looked into calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` in response to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` of the `bgContext` but by the time that's called the changes have already been made and the KVO stuff has already been triggered.

I tried adding the following but end up in an infinite loop:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"pupils"])
    {
        [self.school.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.school mergeChanges:YES];
        self.contentArray = [self.school starPupils];
    }
}
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"pupils"])
    {
        if (self.contentArray == [self.school starPupils])
        {
            /*
             self.contentArray is currently pointing at previous fetched starPupils
             we need to reset the object to a faulted state
             this will twigger another KVO notification for @"pupils" but the code within this if statement will not be executed again
             */
            [self.school.managedObjectContext refreshObject:self.school mergeChanges:YES];
            self.contentArray = [self.school starPupils];
        }
    }
}
```

which works but doesn't feel optimal. Do you have any better suggestions or references to best practice?